# How to use AspectJ + Lombok + Maven + IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj, lombok, aspectj-maven-plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <reweavable>false</reweavable>
                    <!-- this is important: start-->
                    <sources/>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                    <!-- this is important: end-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- The right phase is very important! Compile and weave aspects after all classes compiled by javac -->
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

According to the standard, the aspectj-maven-plugin provides weaving during compilation. But Lombok is a compile-time preprocessor.
Therefore, in order for the weaving to occur after the code is compiled, the following is necessary.

In the plugin:

```
<forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile> и <sources/>
```

You also need to turn off the autobuild in Intellij Idea.
And execute the following command:

```
mvn clean compile install -Pdev
```

Only as a result of this command, the necessary weaving begins! Because of the "install" command.

Tell me, please, why is the weaving happening only thanks to this command? Or are other command options possible, for example, so that tests are not pulled up, etc.?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with the `weaveDirectory` option? Why are you using it? What is wrong with the default directory? Your plugin settings look a bit weird, and you seem to be making a simple matter unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Oh OK, this is about Lombok. Sorry, neither the subject nor any tag pointed to it, you only mentined it in passing somewhere in the mioddle of your long question. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999300/1082681), showing how to weave aspects into lomboked code inside as single module and how to delegate to Maven from IntelliJ IDEA. But actually, I do recommend the second approach with creating a separate Maven module for the weaving step. There also is a link to a sample GitHub repository showing both approaches.

Comment: FYI, I changed the subject and the tags on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You also need to turn off the autobuild in Intellij Idea. And execute the following command:
>
> ```
> mvn clean compile install -Pdev
> ```

the statement above is not correct from AspectJ perspective. There are three (if do not pay attention to `Spring API`) modes to use AspectJ:

- compile time - when we need to compile `native aspectJ (.aj) syntax` files or use `inter-type declarations`
- post-compile time - we compile sources using `javac` and after that `ajc` processes resulting classes - that is your case cause you have specified `<sources/>`
- load time weaving - that requires to either specify `-javaagent` in JVM arguments or have specialised classloader

technically, from `maven lifecycle` perspective everything should work fine in case of post-compile time weaving, however IDEs typically do not trigger `maven lifecycle` when you are pressing green arrow near `#main` or `@Test` method, instead of that IDEs try to analyse project object model (`pom`) and make some assumptions about target classpath and dependencies. Unfortunately, IDEs do not support all maven plugins and that is the main reason why sometimes something does not work as expected (for example, IntelliJ do not support code generators like `OpenAPI` or `Axis2`, that is why we place that stuff into separate maven modules/projects and run `mvn install`). It seems that purpose of your `mvn ... install` is to place *correct* jar into `.m2/repository` and give IDE a chance to pick up that jar.

---

UPD. Some explanations....

Let consider a case when we need to run individual unit test, from `maven` perspective that would be something like:

```
mvn -am clean test -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod*
```

and `maven` will launch it without facing any difficulties, because before `test` step it will start `compile` and `test-compile` steps, where `javac` and `ajc` do the required job. Unfortunately, from developer perspective the maven command mentioned above "takes ages", and that is the reason why IDE tries to optimise that process by compiling only changed classes, unfortunately, if IDE does not support AspectJ (for example, IntelliJ CE does not) or does not recognise maven configuration it has no chance to produce expected output.

Your case is even more complicated because you are using `lombok`, which is not compatible with `ajc` (or vice versa), so to produce correct classes you need first compile sources by `javac` and then postprocess output by `ajc`.

If your goal is to somehow simplify IDE setup for particular project I would recommend the following:

- provide reproducible example, describe your goals and difficulties you have faced with
- try to install AspectJ plugin (if you are not on IntelliJ CE), it seems it has some useful options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It turns out that the command "mvn clean compile install -Pdev" is executed correctly, i.e. weaving occurs (in fact). But this is not correct, since the "<sources/>" element in the plugin should push the weaving itself after launching the program through the green arrow? Did I get it right?

Comment: It turns out that this is not possible due to the features of the IDE. Does this apply to all IDEs? I use Intellij Idea.
Could you clarify this phrase, please? Is this the solution? What needs to be saved in the jar? "It seems that purpose of your mvn ... install is to place correct jar into .m2/repository and give IDE a chance to pick up that jar."

Answer (score 0):

Found this on JetBrain bug tracking system:

> To fix this, you need to go to Project Structure, Modules, select
> AspectJ and check Post-compile weave mode. This will ensure ajc runs
> after Lombok and can see the generated classes.

Worked for me

Comment: This setting will be overwritten, if you re-import the Maven project, either manually or with Maven auto-import. I always have auto-import active, because Maven is the leading build tool in all my projects. Therefore, this is a temporary workaround, not a solution. See also [IDEA-342000](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-342000).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I voted for this issue in your Tracking system as this config is very common  (Lombok+aspectJ+maven/gradle)