# AspectJ configuration / setup - pointcuts not firing

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to get my first AspectJ aspect running. Setup looks ok to me, following the documentation I can find. e.g.

- developers site: https://github.com/kriegaex/org.aspectj
- set up instructions: https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/developer/IDE.md
- join point examples: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html

But no aspect will fire, no matter what options I have tried during all today.

I believe the pointcuts is correctly pointing to my method call because I was getting the error about pointcuts not being used when I changed it. (Thats not happening now - dont know what I did :-())

So is the problem in the setup? The pointcuts? How do you go about de-bugging such a situation? Am I missing something in the docs?

POM

```xml
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
            <!--
            <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>       <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>  <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <sources/>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>
                <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>warning</Xlint>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
   

<dependencies>
.....
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dev.aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

ASPECT

```java
public aspect   MdDOMAINChildAspect {

    pointcut myExceptionHandlerPointcut(): execution(void mdDOMAIN.MdDOMAINInstance.testCall() );

    before(): myExceptionHandlerPointcut() {
        System.out.println("-------------- Aspect Advice Logic ---------------");
    }
```

CLASS

```java
@Data
public class MdDOMAINInstance {


    @MdDOMAINChildAnnotation(selectName = "Indicators")
    public MdDOMAINInstance selectFilingIndicators() throws NoSuchMethodException {

        testCall();

        Method m=this.getClass().getMethod("selectFilingIndicators");
        MdDOMAINChildAnnotation metaidAnnotation=m.getAnnotation(MdDOMAINChildAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("Annotation: " + metaidAnnotation.selectName());

        return this;
    }

    public void testCall()
    {
        System.out.println("In testCall()");
        return ;
    }
}
```

TEST

```java
class MdDOMAINInstanceTest {

    @Test
    void selectFilingIndicatorsTest() throws NoSuchMethodException {
        MdDOMAINInstance mdDOMAINInstance = new MdDOMAINInstance().selectFilingIndicators();
    }
}
```

MAVEN TEST RUN

```
clean test -Dtest=MdDOMAINInstanceTest -f pom.xml
```

MAVEN TEST RUN OUTCOME

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=....IdeaProjects\us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=52349:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.3.2 clean test -Dtest=MdDOMAINInstanceTest
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for us-MYROOT:us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 117, column 22
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 20, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< us-MYROOT:us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 >--------------
[INFO] Building us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Deleting .....IdeaProjects\us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to .....IdeaProjects\us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.14.0:compile (default) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to .....IdeaProjects\us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.14.0:test-compile (default) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[WARNING] You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl
Lombok supports: OpenJDK javac, ECJ
    <unknown source file>:<no line information>

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ us-MYROOT-DOMAIN-004 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running mdDOMAIN.MdDOMAINInstanceTest
In testCall()
Annotation: Indicators
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 s - in mdDOMAIN.MdDOMAINInstanceTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.238 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-21T20:14:46+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If there was a public Intellij project with a working AspectJ example, that would be a great help

Comment: You do not need an IntelliJ project, because if you activate AspectJ support for IntelliJ, it will automatically configure the project correctly when auto-importing a correct Maven project.

Comment: How about some feedback to my answer? I think it is rather impolite to ask for help in public and then keep your helpers waiting.

Comment: I very much appreciate the help @kriegaex. Client work as bumped this problem, so I will be trying again after that problem is solved. Certainly I will give feedback then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried without Lombok in order to avoid [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681)? Try doing manually in your test class what the Lombok annotation does instead.

After we have established that this solves the problem, we can start looking into [possible workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999300/1082681). If this really is your first AspectJ problem, you should not start with a difficult mix like AspectJ + Lombok.

Besides, if your `@Data` class is immutable, you might not need Lombok at all and could use a recent Java version and native Java records for that.